# Chrome Native Messaging unable to invoke host on Linux ubuntu

Tags: c#, linux, chrome-native-messaging

I am trying to invoke a host written in C# from Chrome Extension using Native messaging. The same code works fine on windows, but in Linux after changing the manifest json to user or system folder also its not working.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No #Andrej I am not getting any errors. The js works fine as i have put console.log and the results appears there

Comment: There was permission issue. It is resolved